# Programming Project (Course Project) Need Help. Read Grammar, output Chomsky

Tags: lambda, production, context-free-grammar

So I have been assigned this project and have been giving it the old college try but I am a little lost on how to go about it. The idea is you're given a txt file with a grammar in the form:

- V: S, A, B, C
- T: a, b
- S: S
- P:
- S -> aAaA|aABBA
- A -> AaaA|$
- B -> bB|bbC
- C -> B

These productions rules won't be the only ones tested but that's just an example.

So the first step is to read in the program.
The next step is to remove Lambda ($) productions.
and the final step is to remove unit productions.

I am ... the way I'm removing lambda productions is not the best way I think.

Here's how I'm doing it.

So first, use getline to read in the file.
Next use some loops to go through a file.

Now in an array, I've stored the non terminals that correspond to a rule with a lambda production, so keep that in mind.

So, while going through each character in each production, check if that character is the same as one in the array of the non terminals that denote lambda productions (excluding the index 0 because that's the start of the production)

if you find a match, mark that index you're on

so say your going through S.

S -> a (no problem)
s -> aA (Ok a bit of a problem)

instead of writing the A, don't. skip over it and then using another loop, print out the remaining chunk of that production rule (that is, print out until you hit a bar)
so we get
S -> aaA

now draw a bar

S -> aaA|
now return the index to the first character in this chunk, here being a. From there, rewrite the character up through where you first hit the non terminal.

S -> aaA|aA

now continue looping through to find the next non terminal that's a lambda

S -> aaA | aAaA (here we are)

draw a bar

S -> aaA | aAa |

move back to beginning, continue through

S -> aaA | aAa | aAaA

continue reading through the grammar and outputing each characters and repeat this process to get

S -> aaA | aAa | aAaA | aABB | aBBA | aABBA

at the end of all the code, I have two loops that check for the original bars in the grammar (i replace them with !'s when I did it) and then output at the end the form that has all lambda productions as lambdas giving

S -> aaA | aAa | aAaA | aa | aABB | aBBA | aABBA | aBB

I'm going to include the code here but, be warned,... it's rough. It's rough enough that I can't actually get it to fall nicely under the codeing blocks in here so i'm going link it.

[Code](http://pastebin.com/78yv3czJ)

I appreciate any ideas on how you would undertake this project or if i'm doing something blatantly wrong.

The code currently throws out some errors (which i'm pretty sure are the cause of me reading some empty characters somewhere) but if you ignore them it'll spit out to console the right thing... mostly.

Appreciate any help, thank you for taking the time to read all this mess.

Comment: The link to the code doesn't work (requires password), but anyway: Your question isn't really about the code, is it? I suggest removing the C++ tag, too.

Comment: Ahh testicles, right one second.

Yup, there we go. Fixed that.

Comment: So you want to write a program to convert a grammar into [Chomsky Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form)? Is that correct?

Comment: Also cannot read the code, but, for what it is worth, it seems like you are trying to do this as text manipulation.  Instead, read the grammar into a data structure (some kind of tree), and then manipulate the tree structure for the transformations.  At the end, dump out the final tree.

Comment: Alright I have uploaded it to pastebin, that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the architecture I would recommend:

1. Define the metagrammar of the grammar (the syntax of the grammar productions you are using)
2. Write a simple tokenizer for that metagrammar
3. Write a handwritten recursive decent parser based on metagrammar to parse and create a syntax tree for each input grammar production
4. Manipulate the syntax trees according the CNF rules
5. Generate the output from the modified syntax trees.

**Example meta grammar:**

```
production:
    nonterminal ':' alternatives

alternatives:
    alternative,
    alternative ',' alternatives

alternative:
    symbols

symbols:
    symbol,
    symbol symbols

symbol:
    terminal,
    nonterminal,
    '$'

etc..
```

Comment: I use the word metagrammar to disambiguate the input grammar from the grammar of the input grammar (hence the "meta" grammar).  I'll make a start on it for you

Comment: I have a hard time grasping meta things, but thank you. Appreciate whatever the start is that you give me.

Comment: Ive added a start on it in my post.

Comment: Ooooh! This stuff, ok yea this is familiar.

Comment: Oh christ this is still hard. Thanks though.

Comment: Have you studied how to make a tokenizer and a recursive decent parser in a previous course?  If not I would start there.  Go through the CS143 material from Aiken at Stanford: http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs143/, His lectures are up on youtube here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm0QQO-WZlM and the standard text is "the dragon book" by aho sethi ullman: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools.  You want chapters 2, 3 and 4.  You just need the frontend parsing stuff, not the backend code generation parts.

Comment: It's been a couple of semesters so it's not fresh in my memory. I'll look at this stuff though.

Comment: And i'm honestly not sure how to go about it. I've spent so much time already on this that I'm burn out and am forgetting even the basics of how to start a tree.

Comment: Start by writing a validator that just reads an input grammar and checks whether it is wellformed and matches the metagrammar.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20143/discussion-between-neojb1989-and-andrew-tomazos-fathomling)

Comment: So I understand what a toknizer is, it spkits a string into tokens. But what does a tokenize for a metagrammer do? Split strings into the catagories of the meagrammer?

Comment: See the thing is the metagrammar will change depending on what input grammar she gives us. So i imagine i have to grab the terminals and non terminals from the input grammar and use that in the meta grammar. I'm ok with that.

I just don't understand what you mean by a tokenizer for the meta grammar. To me a tokenizer is something that splits up a string based on a certain keycharacter. so like "The Fox Is Red" I can tokenize into an array ( in java) using the split thing to get {The,Fox,Is,Red}. Could you reword that please :)

Comment: Although I didn't go entirely the way you said (That dragon book is a hard read my friend) you did help me in thinking about it the right way so I appreciate that. Thank you :)

Now if you have a really nicely explain psuedocode for doing the CYK Algorithm to check if a string is in a CNF Grammar, that'd be awesome :P